# Creating GUI with multiple function buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI as shown in the attached picture

[image]

I wrote the following code which does the job but not the way I need it to.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkMessageBox as mb
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.messagebox as mb

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

tk.Label(root, text="Python First GUI Template", bg="goldenrod", font="bold").pack()
tk.Label(root, text="").pack()

def addFn():
    a = int(input('enter first number'))
    b = int(input('enter second number'))
    mb.showinfo('showinfo', a+b)

def subtractFn():
    a = int(input('enter first number'))
    b = int(input('enter second number'))
    mb.showinfo('showinfo', a - b)

tk.Button(root, text="Add Function", bg="SkyBlue1", command=addFn).pack()
tk.Label(root, text="").pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Subtract Function", bg="SkyBlue1", command=subtractFn).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So, I have the following problems:

(1) I am not able to create the design as I want in the attached picture in terms of relative color and relative location of "add" and "subtract" buttons.

(2) When I hit the buttons to activate "add" or "subtract" functions, the inputs are required on the console. I need a pop up with input box and drop down for two numbers I want to add. I am looking for following format for "add" function.

[image]

(3) I want to add a "quit" button to close the console when I am done

Comment: The first thing I see is that you are not telling `pack()` where to pack each widget. This will result in the widgets just being placed underneath the last widget that was packed with no arguments. So you will need to specify where to pack with `side=LEFT` or other directions. There are several good tutorials out there on how to use `pack()` and `grid()`. I prefer using `grid()` for an application like this one.

Comment: As for your pop up window problem you can use `askstring` from message box or you can write your own `toplevel()` window to get both strings at once.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to this myself, and unfortunately can't answer most of your questions, but regarding the quit button, I'm thinking you can write a function that calls quit(), just like you would type in order to exit the Python interactive interpreter.  Then you link that function to a button just as you did for the first two buttons. This is the same idea with a lambda expression:

```
from tkinter import *

root =Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

Button(root,text="QUIT",bg='Red',command=lambda:(quit())).pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

This here is a TKinter frame that gives you a red quit button at the bottom whose sole reason for existence is to quit the frame it's in.

Regarding the layout, I think the pack method requires you to indicate where  pack should prefer to put the widget, but doesn't give you much absolute control.  Wouldn't grid method allow for better alignment?

Why do your input boxes have to pop out? Why can't they be embedded into the app frame? I would think that would eliminate some difficulty with the issue, no?

Sorry this isn't the most helpful answer ever... but I hope it gives you something to work with until someone more knowledgeable happens by. Cheers.

Comment: The `.pack()` method could be used to achieve this result through the use of the `side` attribute and `Frame` widgets but you're right in saying that `.grid()` is probably more suitable.

Comment: You answer seams more suited as a comment. Maybe you can write a small bit of code to show an example and then explain why that example is accurate. This would go a long way to improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mike - SMT, I agree with you, and felt that way myself as I was writing it. I just didn't know my way around well enough. I appreciate your feedback, and I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could do this, the simplest being using `.grid()` instead of `.pack()`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

title = Label(root, text="Python First GUI Template")
add = Button(root, text="Add")
subtract = Button(root, text="Subtract")
_quit = Button(root, text="Quit")

title.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
add.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
subtract.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
_quit.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

`.grid()` allows you to place widgets on the window in a grid fashion, imagine there are cells which you are placing each widget into, whereas `.pack()` by default will place items stacked on top of eachother unless certain attributes are given values.

You could also use `.place()` which allows you to place the widgets based on coordinates but this requires a lot more effort make responsive to window size changes or adding new widgets and the like.

---

On a side note, Stack Overflow is not a free programming resource, we will not write programs for you based on a list of demands. There are plenty of freelance programmers who are happy to do that in exchange for money. I would recommend in future that rather than asking a question about an incredibly well documented library with over 17000 questions on Stack Overflow, a large number of which are about the difference in the three geometry managers you instead find a tutorial or ask a colleague, schoolmate, teacher or friend for help.

Comment: I don't think `place()` is more complicated. Rather its takes more effort to keep the GUI updated when using `place()`. Also your comment about not writing the code for someone I think might not apply to this question. Normally I would reserve that kind of comment for people who have made no attempt to write the code themselves. However in this case the OP has attempted to write a GUI and shown their code.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I concour with your statement on the `.place()` method, I was oversimplifying, I'll change that now.

Comment: @Zanam. Stack Overflow is for coding question yes however not even trying to search for the answer before asking is what Ethan is referring to with "poor questions". Your exact problem on the layout not being what you want has been asked countless times and the fact that you asked the question with as much rep as you have show you have put little to no effort in researching your question before asking it. The stack overflow community polices itself and its effective at keeping the quality of Questions/Answer higher than other sites.

Comment: @Zanam And I would like to specify that none of this was intended as an attack on you or your skills. Merely adherence to site ideology.

Comment: What does quality of question mean? Should I call my math model implementation questions super genius as it was too hard for anyone to have an answer ? My tensorflow implementation has the best answer as: "TF guys are not God".

Comment: @Zanam: You were given an answer. I answered in the comments and Ethan gave you direction on how to use grid for the formatting. I can easily write exactly what it is you need and paste the code. You have not received an answer tailored to your exact question because the question does not deserve this level of support. If you don't understand what a good question is then I have 2 links for you that is given out to everyone who does not know what a good question is. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Zanam: You need to understand Stack Overflow is not your typical Q/A. If the problem you are having has already been asked many times and can easily be found with a few minutes of search with google or on the site directly then you should probably not ask the question.

Comment: @Zanam Also are you able to tell me which question was answered with "TF guys are not God" because that answer is wholly off topic.